# Converting video ID inside square brackets to YouTube video links

Tags: php, regex

I have the following strings:

```
this is a video [youtube erfsdf3445] test
this is a video [youtube we466f] test
```

I'm trying to build a regular expression that replaces `[youtube erfsdf3445]` with the the corresponding YouTube video link, for example `www.youtube.com/watch?v=erfsdf3445`. The text enclosed in square brackets is used for video ID.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I've rephrased your question a bit. If it's different from what you're trying to achieve, please feel free to modify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is `/\[youtube ([^\]]+)\]/`.

**Autopsy**:

- `\[` *a literal `[` character*
- `youtube[space]` *the literal string "youtube " (with a space)*
- `([^\]]+)` *a capturing group (this is `$1`):*

  - `[^\]]+` *any character that isn't `\]` (that's a literal `]`) matched 1 or more times (can't be empty)*
- `\]` *a literal `]` character*

**Debuggex**:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**In code**:

If you don't want to do any URL encoding, you can simply use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```
<?php
    $string = 'this is a video [youtube erfsdf3445] test';

    $string = preg_replace('/\[youtube ([^\]]+)\]/', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1', $string);

    var_dump($string);
    //string(62) "this is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erfsdf3445 test"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/105949)

---

On the other hand - if you **do** want to use URL encoding and you use PHP 5.3+ you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) with an anonymous function:

```
<?php
    $string = 'this is a video [youtube erfsdf3445] test';

    $string = preg_replace_callback('/\[youtube ([^\]]+)\]/', function($match) {
        return 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . urlencode($match[1]);
    }, $string);

    var_dump($string);
    //string(62) "this is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erfsdf3445 test"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/105945)

---

If you use anything less than PHP 5.3, you can still use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback), just not with an anonymous function:

```
<?php
    $string = 'this is a video [youtube erfsdf3445] test';

    function replace_youtube_callback($match) {
        return 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . urlencode($match[1]);
    };

    $string = preg_replace_callback('/\[youtube ([^\]]+)\]/', 'replace_youtube_callback', $string);

    var_dump($string);
    //string(62) "this is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erfsdf3445 test"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/105946)

Comment: Since youtube URLs are just letters and numbers, you probably don't even need the callback, just a `preg_replace`

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox Check the edit I made a few minutes ago, and about a minute ago moved to the top.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Hadn't updated the display. I already upvoted anyway.

Comment: Links to documentation, working code, demo, explanation of what's happening. You've got my vote already!